# IP range in pg_hba.conf for remote access to pgsql

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a postgresql database on a machine with ip 10.240.81.76. I need to allow remote access to this database from machines 10.240.122.64, 10.240.243.143,...10.240.x.y . I know that i need to make an entry in the pg_hba.conf like the following:

```
host all all 10.10.29.0/24 trust
```

What should be the IP range i should be using for the ips in my case ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easy answer is

```
host <database_name> all 10.240.0.0/16 md5
```

But much depends on your network configuration. Also note the use of `md5` for the authentication method; usually only local addresses should use `trust`.

This assumes that you know the machines on the 10.240.0.0/16 network. That is, obviously, a private range but there can be up to 16K computers in that range. If you are uncertain, make multiple entries in `pg_hba.conf` for individual addresses or C-class ranges of which you are certain that they need to connect to your server.